# How to change ForeColor of ComboBox's Selected Item?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, combobox

Is it possible to change appearance for selected (not in drop down!) item?

combobox.ForeColor is changing the text color only for all items into drop-down list.

**Edit:**
Variants are beelow, ours is

```
 public static void CBoxDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs args)
    {
        var box = sender as ComboBox;
        if (box == null || args.Index < 0 || args.Index >= box.Items.Count)
            return;

        e.DrawBackground();
        var data = box.Tag as ControlData;
        var color = (args.State & DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit) == 0 || data == null || !data.IsInDefaultState
            ? e.ForeColor : GetDefaultColor(e.ForeColor);
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(color))
        {
            args.Graphics.DrawString(box.Items[args.Index].ToString(), args.Font, brush, args.Bounds.X, args.Bounds.Y);
        }
        args.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

Comment: What style of combobox are you using? Simple, DropDown, or DropDownList?

Comment: See my answer below—you need to change that to DropDown, instead. There's no way to get a DropDownList to paint in a custom color, given the way it's themed under Windows Vista and later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to change the `FlatStyle` to Popup or Flat to make this work. And you probably don't want to do that in the first place, because those styles tend to look really ugly when compared to the rest of your application's interface. Native Windows controls use a 3D-style appearance; the Flat and Popup styles are designed for Web or Windows Mobile applications, where they are a better fit.

I assume that you're asking this question because you have already written code to change the foreground color of the text displayed in the combobox, but have noticed that it isn't working under Windows Vista or later. That's because when the `DropDownList` style of combobox changed to look more like a button in those versions of Windows, it also lost support for custom text color. Instead, the selected text is always displayed in the standard "Window Text" color. Compare the `DropDownList` style to the regular `DropDown` style combobox:

[image: Comparing the DropDownList style to the DropDown style under Windows Vista or later]

Visually, the two comboboxes look the same in earlier versions of Windows, but not under Vista and later. **The key to getting your custom foreground color to appear is changing the [`DropDownStyle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle.aspx) of your combobox control to `DropDown`** (which is actually the default).

I also like to set the [`FlatStyle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.flatstyle.aspx) to `System` so that you get all the nifty fade-in and fade-out effects offered by the native Windows controls. The `Standard` style attempts to emulate those effects in managed code, but it just doesn't have quite the right feel. I care about the little things.

Then you can use the following code (as originally suggested in Adrian's answer):

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   // Set custom combobox styles
   comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
   comboBox1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;

   // Attach relevant event handler methods
   comboBox1.DropDown += new EventHandler(comboBox1_DropDown);
   comboBox1.DropDownClosed += new EventHandler(comboBox1_DropDownClosed);
}

void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Optionally, revert the color back to the default
   // when the combobox is dropped-down
   //
   // (Note that we're using the ACTUAL default color here,
   //  rather than hard-coding black)
   comboBox1.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
}

void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Change the color of the selected text in the combobox
   // to your custom color
   comboBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

To produce the following effect:

[image: ComboBox showing selected text in red]

Comment: +1, more complete than my answer. Changing the style to DropDown will make it editable and that should be handled if one would need it as read only.

Comment: This is not always good, to have editable element :) And as your image, look&feel for combox is changed too.

Comment: @Lonli: You're right, unfortunately programming is about compromises. As I explained in my answer, there's no way to get the new themed control *and* still be able to customize the font color. You either need to change the style of control, disable theming on that particular control altogether (which will have the same effect), or give up on specifying a custom font color.

Comment: Yep) Our varint is in the first post.

Answer (score 5):

If you can change the FlatStyle of the combo box to Popup or Flat the color of the selected item will also change when you change the ForeColor.

[image: Screenshot]

To change only the color of the selected item you can implement some kind of workaround and change the ForeColor each time the DropDown is opened or closed.

Code Sample:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;

        comboBox1.DropDown += new EventHandler(comboBox1_DropDown);
        comboBox1.DropDownClosed += new EventHandler(comboBox1_DropDownClosed);
    }

    void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }

    void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Cody Gray' sugestion and add it to has the same DropDownList Style behaviour:

```
private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

On this way the user can't edit the combobox.